# Went live on the App Store, Game Center not working?

Tags: ios, game-center

It worked fine in sandbox mode when I was developing, although it had  some hiccups(like achievement alerts not showing up).

But now, it's been approved for sale and it's now live in iTunes. However, I downloaded it and went into game center only to find "No Items". Does anyone know what the problem is? Maybe the server needs time to go online?

Comment: I figured it out: for me, time was the answer. I waited for a while and it's now online :)